# How to separate data based on different variable values

Tags: r, analytics

I have a dataset of around 1.5 L observations and 2 variables: `name` and `amount`. `name` can have same value again and again, for example a name `ABC` can appear 50 times in the dataset.

I want a new data frame with two variables: `name` and `total amount`, where each `name` has a unique value and `total amount` is the sum of all amounts in previous dataset. For example if `ABC` appears three times with `amount` == `1`, `2` and `3` respectively in the previous dataset then in the new dataset, `ABC` will only appear one time with total `amount` == `6`.

Comment: What have you tries so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.table` for big datasets:

```
library(data.table)
res<- setDT(df)[, list(Total_Amount=sum(amount)), by=name]
```

Or use `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    summarise(Total_Amount=sum(amount))
```

Or as suggested by @hrbrmstr,

```
 count(df, name, wt=amount)
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 df <- data.frame(name=sample(LETTERS[1:5], 25, replace=TRUE),
                               amount=sample(150,25, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: You can just do `df %>% count(name, wt=amount)` now in `dplyr`. Hadley ported the `plyr`-esque `count` idiom over to `dplyr` very recently.